# iOS: how to determine if button is dragged into a specified area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an idea for a game where the user drags coins(buttons in my case) onto a yellow image ( UIView image that is yellow in the background) to satisfy a random amount they are suppose to calculate. My question arises when I have to find out the location of the coins once they are dragged. Currently my yellow box's coordinates are 359 x, 376 y, width 375, height 593.

```
-(IBAction)dragged_out:(id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;    
    selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}
```

This is the method that I have created to allow the users to drag my coins around. Any suggestions will be helpful as I am running out of ideas. Also one more question is that my dime and nickel image are dragging very smooth when moved but when my quarter image is dragged it is very choppy. Does this have to do with the image itself? I am using .png format for the pictures.

Thanks,

Ryan W

Comment: `CGRectContainsRect()` checks if one rectangle completely encompasses another, not just if they intersect. From your question, i think they just intersect. so You're looking for `CGRectIntersectsRect()`.. take a look at those methods, you can attain what you want to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(selButton.frame, your_area_frame)) {

      // button is within the area.

} else {

     // Button is not is the area.
}
```

Comment: Hi Erik, the difference between intersects and contains is that for intersects the coin would only have to touch the yellow box where as contains, the whole coin would have to be within the yellow box. Is this correct?

Comment: Also for the parameters of CGRectIntersectsRect, it must be of type CGRect. How do I go about converting selButton.center to a CGRect?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to find out the location of the **UIButton *selected** , you can use

```
xcoordinate =  selected.frame.origin.x;
ycoordinate =  selected.frame.origin.y;
```